# file_get_contents doesn't work on Ubuntu on my own VPS server

Tags: php, ubuntu, post, request, vps

I'm trying to use php function `file_get_contents` in my php file.

URL of request is my own API URL from the same server, for example I make request in file https://example.com/file.php to URL https://example.com/categories/get/.

file_get_contents to this URL works from another server and from mobile applications (Android, iOS). I can successfully make file_get_contents to another server and it will respond me. CURL doesn't work, but requests using JavaScript (using XMLHttpRequest) work successfully.

Error says `failed to open stream: Connection refused`.

I have VPS on Ubuntu 18.4, Vesta Panel, PHP 7.2. As far as I know there are no firewalls, iptables or something else.

Can you help me? Maybe some hints about wrong php settings?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hi Ruslan. Please show us your code (php file). You can also show us part of your php settings. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This helps me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940198/using-file-get-contents-or-curl-to-url-on-same-server